# Editing a deleted Q provides contradictory feedback

Tags: bug

While attempting to revise a deleted question, I read the SE text below:

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center,
>   please edit your question.

I clicked `edit`, did a copy and paste to simplify a paragraph, and after a bit of moving things around, the following text banner, (in white on orange) pops up at the top of the page:

```
This post has been deleted - no more edits are allowed
```

If "*no more edits are allowed*", then why does clicking on `edit` still work?

Before the `no more edits` banner pops up, the user is permitted several edit operations, (typing a little text, deleting chars, etc.).  This seems like a waste of SE's resources, and worse, it's a waste of user time.

If the user perseveres, and clicks `Save Edits`, the edit saves *anyway*.

So:

1. The SE texts contradict: `please edit` vs. `no more edits`.
2. The SE page behavior doesn't do what one would expect.  It allows edits, and saves them. (Which is what I'd *prefer*.)

Comment: It's strange because on an old deleted question on the Skeptics site I am unable to click the edit button, and get a tooltip saying I must first undelete it.

Comment: is the question yours or someone else's

Comment: I'm not super-familiar with the system, but you should be able to edit a deleted question while it's deleted.  The reasons this is allowed is because questions are able to be undeleted, and you might want to prepare it to be undeleted before then.  I'm not surprised that this behavior differs based on who deleted your question, but I'm not very familiar with all of those scenarios.  The people on Meta.SE will be more knowledgeable about software-related issues